# What's the meaning of "God would score the toss" (of the dice)?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does **to score** mean here? To keep the score? I understand that the author means that she has no control of the dice. But what does this mean relative to God? Does **score the toss** mean **to keep score**? So God just knows the total points on the dice. Thanks in advance

> God would **score the toss**.

The full text:

> BYU was a competitive school. I’d need a high score—a twenty-seven at least, which meant the top fifteen percent of my cohort. I was sixteen, had never taken an exam, and had only recently undertaken anything like a systematic education; still I registered for the test. It felt like throwing dice, like the roll was out of my hands. God would **score the toss**.

*Educated* by Tara Westover

Comment: Taking the test is so chancy that it's like throwing dice. A high number (presumably) means getting a high score, and likewise a low number, a low score. TW takes the test (throws the dice) and the result is in God's hands. God will "score the toss," i.e., tell TW what the dice read when they come to rest, and that revelation will come by BYU informing her of her test score.

Comment: I think it's at the very least "unusual / loose" phrasing - what she obviously *means* is her exam score was "in the lap of the gods" (she had no control over the result, as with tossing / rolling dice). Not really a usage worth remembering (and certainly don't ***copy*** it).

Comment: ...in which context it may be worth noting that the ***only*** contextually-relevant occurrence of [***score the toss***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22score+the+toss%22) (meaning ***decide the outcome***, as in ringside judges scoring / deciding the outcome of a boxing match) in Google Books is this very one from Westover.

Comment: Thanks a lot 